# how i can select only the type of the variables in the drupal watchdog database table?

Tags: php, database, drupal, drupal-7

*****~PLZ HELP~***I want to spesialize the variables and take the type e.g 'Notice', 'Error'..In this code that follows execute something like this

3710       a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:6:"Notice";s:8:"!message";s:24:"Undefined variable: path";s:9:"%function";s:3:"l()";s:5:"%file";s:44:"c";s:5:"%line";i:2469;s:14:"severity_level";i:5;}

3711       a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:6:"Notice";s:8:"!message";s:24:"Undefined variable: path";s:9:"%function";s:3:"l()";s:5:"%file";s:44:"/c";s:5:"%line";i:2511;s:14:"severity_level";i:5;}

3712       a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:7:"Warning";s:8:"!message";s:141:"Missing argument 2 for l(), called in on line 171 and defined";s:9:"%function";s:3:"l()";s:5:"%file";s:44:"";s:5:"%line";i:2458;s:14:"severity_level";i:4;}

3713       a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:6:"Notice";s:8:"!message";s:24:"Undefined variable: path";s:9:"%function";s:3:"l()";s:5:"%file";s:44:"";s:5:"%line";i:2469;s:14:"severity_level";i:5;}**

```
    function blabla_page() {

          // Begin building

 the query.
      $query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
        ->extend('PagerDefault')
        ->orderBy('wid')
        ->fields('th')
        ->limit(10);

    // Fetch the result set.
    $result = $query->execute();

      // Loop through each item and add to the $rows array.
      foreach ($result as $row) {
        $rows[] = array(
        $row -> wid,
        $row -> variables,
       );
      }
    // Headers for theme_table().
      $header = array('ID', 'Message');

    // Format output.
      $output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows)). theme('pager');
         return $output;
       }
```

Comment: This core module [dblog](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/dblog) actually does this for the types of items you are trying to get from the watchdog. Is this doing what you need already?

Comment: i want to put it into my code.... When i have $row -> variables it shows me the word Notice or Warning but i want in my table only this word not all this things that i see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information in the field is serialized  this should do it.

```
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $message1=unserialize($row->variables);
    if($message1['%type']){
      $rows[] = array(
      $row -> wid,
      $message1['%type'],
    );
   }
  }
```

Now the output will only be added to the rows array when the %type item exists

Comment: In the table i cannot see nothing and  it also say this...      Notice: Undefined index: %type in blabla_page() (line 155 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/blabla.module.

Comment: if($message1['%type'] = 'Notice')
  and if i put this in my code it shows me atable full of notices but if in ID i put variables i saw that the type -> Warnings is shown as Notices....i do not know what is happening

Comment: Please look into [php if statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) if($message1['%type'] == 'Notice') will only show Notices to show warnings aswell you would have to define it 
if($message1['%type'] == 'Notice'||'Warning')  Basically  its doing  this: if the message array item of %type is a Notice or Warning Do the code

Comment: Mildly confused as to why this is no longer marked as complete, As I have answered your question

Comment: i cannot understand the first lines of the table are with no values and it says "Notice: Undefined index: %type in blabla() (line 160 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/blabla/blabla.module".. And in the 12th page of the table has the correct values.

Comment: have you copied the updated code?   it works as expected on my test. can you provide a link to your site so I can see it

Comment: I want one more thing how can i write out the message of the severity??i do not want the ID list but the 'message'. If i delete wid and write message it writes me out "%type: !message in %function (line %line of %file)." This is my last question I promise :D

Comment: chnage  this      $header = array('Message'); then  remove $row -> wid, from the foreach

Comment: I want to write me down the messages from the database table 'watchdog'...e.g Notice: Undefined index:blabla  in blabla_page() (line 160 of /var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/blabla/blabla.module).

Comment: now it shows me : %type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).

Comment: you do not find something ah?? :'( :'(

Comment: Could you help plz?? :(